# Can I use S-Video output converted to VGA for daily work?

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, vga, s-video

I have here a video card with a VGA output. Next to that, it has also an S-Video output.

I am thinking on upgrading my system into a dual-desktop direction, by buying an s-video -> vga converter and using it as a secondary display.

Unfortunately, I can't find anywhere information, if it works or not.

I am curious about the usability of the s-video -> vga conversion, so

- *"you will get at most 576x576 pixel, which is not usable for work"*, is an acceptable answer.
- The trivial *"Buy a dual vga card for $5"* is not an acceptable answer (this question is only about the feasibility of the s-video -> vga conversion).
- *"Yes by me it drives an 1024x768 monitor, it is my cutting page"*, is an acceptable answer.

It is a common, not graphic-intensive workstation for common office work.

Comment: No,  S-video is not suitable for a computer console unless you like to look at a 720x480 screen.  Use it only to display standard definition video.

Comment: @sawdust It is a standardized thing in the S-Video? To me, it doesn't sound unimaginable to produce video output in any resolution (which resolution would be set by me, in the display properties). So, it is unimaginable to have an S-Video output in a resolution which differs from 720x480?

Comment: Sure, there's 640x480 for a 4:3 aspect ratio.  S-video is for video, not computer graphics. End of story.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have here a video card with a VGA output. Next to that, it has also an S-Video output.

The VGA port is for computer text and graphics on a computer monitor.
The S-Video port is for connection to a television to display video (e.g. a movie from the DVD drive) at standard definition (i.e. NTSC or PAL).
Standard definition NTSC video is fixed at 480 (interlaced) horizontal lines. (Actually there's a total of 525 lines.)
The resolution of S-video is not considered suitable for modern computer text and graphics work, where the minimum resolution configurable in Windows 7 is 800x600 progressive.

The degradation of the PC's desktop text by converting to 480i S-video, and then back to some higher-resolution VGA would not be readable IMO.
You could probably simulate the degradation by grabbing a full-resolution screen capture, downscaling that image to 720x480 (e.g. use `Resize by pixels` in MS Paint), and then upscaling it (use `zoom`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use S-Video as an output and in theory it can be converted to VGA, but you'll need an active device between them. The S-Video has 4-pins where the VGA is using a 15-pin-connector. In practice this means that you'll maybe get some picture with the active converter, but there will be no automatic resolution detection and the image might go far over the edges of the screen, or there might be black borders on all sides. In my opinion S-Video to VGA conversion is unusable for any kind of work (with those resolutions PowerPoint won't most probably fit on the screen).

Comment: Thank you the answer! But: I know what is the optimal resolution of the possible monitors (1366x768 or 1280x800), so if there is no automatic resolution detection, what if I simply set it in the display properties?

Comment: You could do that, but it would most probably lead to [overscan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overscan). And the image would also be ulgy, since in S-Video there is only 1 minus-pin. In VGA there is a + and a - for each (R, G and B). The converter would simply short the minuses and in theory that's no a good thing. (And off-topic: I once had a tv connected to laptop with straight S-Video cable and...no, the image is very likely going to get unreadable etc.)

Comment: *"S-Video ...carry analog RGB signals"* -- Wrong.  S-video is not RBG, but chrominance and luminance signals for standard definition video.  *"S-Video there is only 1 minus-pin"* -- You're not making any sense.  It's not a differential signal.

Comment: Oh, actually that's true. Sorry, got confused. As sawdust said, VGA and S-Video are carrying different kinds of signals, so you cannot even convert them without an active device. And then there is the problem with the resolution.

Comment: Please see updated answer

Comment: @sawdust Please consider a vote change on the edited answer. Anyways, if you would convert your comment to an answer, I would be happy to accept it.