# Can I connect my monitor to my graphics card through S-Video RCA?

Tags: graphics-card, display, vga, adapter, s-video

I got an old GPU card with two output ports: 1x VGA, 1x S-Video RCA
Unfortunately the VGA port is broken, the image is coloured and I have to hold the cable in a certain position in order for the image to be displayed properly.

I wanted to fix it by soldering but it's pins are not really accessible (not all of them) and I don't have the proper tools to fix it any further.

I want to put this card in an old PC that my father uses. I already put some other old components from other old PCs in it to make it a little faster, and it now works quite well for browsing (Intel Pentium 4, 1.5 Gigs of RAM (dual channel), 40Gb HDD). The only improvement left to do is putting a dedicated GPU in it, and this card is unfortunately the only one that I have which is compatible with this PC, but it's broken... The only other AGP card that I have won't let the PC boot and fires off the beep alarm (just like the one that fires when the PC has no RAM connected), tho it works fine in it's original PC.

The only way that I can think of being able to use this card, except from either getting the tools to repair the VGA port or sending it to a professional, which are both expensive and not worth for such an old card (Some ATI RX9250 with 128MB, if I remember correctly), is to somehow use the S-Video output.

Do you guys know of any way to use a LCD monitor with VGA input with an S-Video RCA output? Is there any kind of adapter or something?
In the worst case scenario, I also have an old, huge CRT monitor that also has RCA ports, including the yellow S-Video... will it work with that at least if I get an RCA-male to RCA-male cable? Of course that wouldn't be really confortable since that monitor is huge (just like a TV - AFAIK it can also be used as one, tho I didn't try it) and so heavy it will probably need a new table to hold it, and I prefer to use it for an even older PC at my grandfather's old place, which is now pretty much empty, because that one is barely ever used anymore.

Notes:
- The monitor and it's cable are fine, I tested them on multiple PCs, including the same PC's VGA output from the motherboard.

Comment: *"S-Video RCA output"*, *"yellow S-Video"* -- S-Video does not use a RCA connector.  S-Video uses a 4-pin DIN connector.  A yellow RCA connector (on consumer gear) is almost always for ***composite video***, which is also 480i.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use S-Video output converted to VGA for daily work?](http://superuser.com/questions/1081018/can-i-use-s-video-output-converted-to-vga-for-daily-work)

Comment: @sawdust thanks for that link, it's a really good question and I found some really interesting comments there. Is it true that S-Video is limited to a low resolution? If that's true then it is of no use since the on-board card supports decent resolutions which look nice and are productive, tho it is somewhat slower. Also, yes, it's a composite video port. I thought that S-Video is actually RCA... I never used them before so I didn't knew the difference.

Answer (score 1):

Conversion between VGA and S-Video is not instantaneaous like HDMI <-> DVI. You need a special converter device. The most popular one is called **KanaaN**.

Search "S-Video to VGA" on Amazon or E-Bay. Costs something between 10 and 20 USD.

Comment: Good answer, that thing looks like it could be a solution to my problem, but unfortunately it is not worth buying. For that price I could just buy another old card with a proper output. I'm more interested in just buying a cable or an adapter at the very most. I'm not willing to spend any money on that PC because it's so old but good enough for my dad... I was just wondering if I can improve it somehow using the things that I already have but without investing (much)